# pandas Series.from_records?

Tags: python, pandas

The `DataFrame.from_records` accepts a list of dictionaries and creates a dataframe, with one column for each key of the dict.

I commonly have data of the format

```
[{'index': 1, value: 5}, {'index': 2, value: 10}]
```

and I want to create a `pd.Series` from it, which would be equivalent to

```
pd.Series([5, 10], index=[1, 2])
```

However, there doesn't seem to exist a similar method for Series.

I end up using `DataFrame.from_records` and then using `squeeze()` to convert it to Series. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: but Series is One-dimensional ndarray, how should look your expected result?

Comment: @blue_note Better in what way? `series = pd.DataFrame(records).squeeze()` doesn't seem too bad

Comment: feels weird creating a dataframe and converting it to series, when you want a series in the first place.

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d1accd032b648c9affd6dce1f81feb9c99422483/pandas/core/sparse/frame.py#L169

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise a Series from a dictionary of key-value pairs (intuitively, this makes more sense than a list of records). On cpython3.6+ (or python3.7+), you may do

```
pd.Series({r['index']: r['value'] for r in records})  

1     5
2    10
dtype: int64
```

Dictionaries preserve insertion order in cpython3.6+ (or python3.7+). On older versions, your ordering may not be guaranteed, so you can sort on the index after.

```
pd.Series({r['index']: r['value'] for r in records}).sort_index()
```

---

You may also use `DataFrame.from_records` and squeeze it into a Series, if you want to make it obvious to someone reading your code that you're initialising a Series from records.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, index=['index']).squeeze()

index
1     5
2    10
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: nice that you mentioned the `sort_index` for lower versions. :)